# Calling Struct to main function from header file

Tags: c, struct

I have two header files and a main program.

Header files are `data.h` and `flight.h`. The main program is `calculateflight.c`.

The data header file has a set of `typedef structs` that contains the variables  required for the program to run.

I have created a headerfile named flightmodel.h that contains the following:

```
#ifndef __FLIGHT_MODEL_H
#define __FLIGHT_MODEL_H
#include "Data.h"

void calculateFlight(speedParamsType *speed, spinParamsType *spin,
                     flightParamsType *fData);

#endif
```

The data.h contains `typedef struct`s like

```
typedef struct {
  float totalSpin;
  float spinAxis;
  float backSpin;
  float sideSpin;
} spinParamsType;
```

There are no errors in the `struct variables`, but I don't know how to call `struct` inside the main function.

```
    void main()
{
     speedParamsType speed;
     spinParamsType spin;
     flightParamsType fData;
     speed.totalSpeed=200.0f;
     speed.launchAngle=30.0f;
     speed.horizontalAngle=5.0f;
     spin.totalSpin=1000.0f;
     flightParamsType fData;
     fData.carry=
     calculateFlightModel(&speed,&spin,&fData);
     getch();
}
```

This is what i have done in the main function.It shows error C2275: 'flightParamsType' : illegal use of this type as an expression
see declaration of 'flightParamsType';
syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fData'

Comment: Well, you can't 'call' structs. You would `#include "data.h"`, have you done that ? If so, what is the actual issue (i.e. show us some compiler errors, code and other relevant info) ?

Comment: Yes I have included it in the main program.See it is like this.I have created a headerfile named flightmodel.h that contains the following:
#ifndef __FLIGHT_MODEL_H
#define __FLIGHT_MODEL_H
#include "Data.h"

void calculateFlight(speedParamsType *speed,spinParamsType *spin, flightParamsType *fData);
The data.h contains typedef structs like typedef struct
{
 float totalSpin;
 float spinAxis;
 float backSpin;
 float sideSpin;
}spinParamsType;
Now I want to call the structs in the main function of my program

Comment: Since you can only call functions in C, not structs, it's a bit hard to know what you mean. You would not do anything different vs having all all that code in your main file vs having them in several files + header files. Now, please update your question with the code posted in your comment here, what you have tried to do in your `main()` function, and any compiler errors you get.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one example of usage, note that besides the `#include` directive, there's nothing special that needs to be done.

```
#include "flight.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   spinParamsType a = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
   spinParamsType b = {2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f, 2.0f};
   flightParamsType c; // I don't know what kind of members this struct have.

   calculateFlight(&a, &b, &c);

    return 0;
}
```

Remember to compile all the source code files and link them together

Comment: Under the spinParamter struct i have 3 variables namely sspin,bspin,totalspin.if i have to give individual values to these variables how do i do that in the main function?

Comment: You have a line that says: `fData.carry=` That's an incomplete statement, it's missing a value and a semicolon. What about `fData.carry= 1234;` ?

Comment: I was about to answer to that.
fData contains the output parameters that should be shown by calculating the spin parameters in the struct.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra, duplicate declaration of `flightParamsType fData` between the statements:

```
     spin.totalSpin=1000.0f;
     flightParamsType fData;
     fData.carry=
     calculateFlightModel(&speed,&spin,&fData);
```

(in addition to the one near the beginning of `main`). That's illegal.